# Compare file sizes from a remote machine bash

Tags: bash, ssh

I copied from a remote machine some files to my machine using sftp:

```
ssh user@remote_host '
find /file/location -type f -maxdepth 1 -size +400000c -name "TEXT_*"
'>> log

cat log | while read line; do

sftp user@remote_host <<EOF
get $line
EOF

done

rm log
```

What I want to do now is check if the file size of the copied files is the same as of the files on the remote machine. This is what I tried:

```
ls -1 TEXT* | while read line;
do var=$(stat "/file/on/current/machine/$line");
   var2=`ssh -n user@remote_host 'ls -l /file/on/remote/$line | cut -d " " -f5 '`;
        if [ "$var" == "$var2" ];
        then
                echo "The file $line has the same dimension!";
        else
                echo "The file $line doesn't have the same dimension";
        fi;
done
```

The problem is that the variable $line is not recognized inside the ssh command and it returns the sizes of all the files on the remote host, not only the ones that were copied.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `$line` is inside single quotes. Variables are only interpolated in double quotes.

```
var2=$(ssh -n user@remote_host "ls -l /file/on/remote/$line | cut -d ' ' -f5 ")
```